# V8 TypedArray performance cliff when bounds check gets eliminated?

Tags: performance, v8

Just for background, I'm writing a bzip2 decompression library in javascript and I don't understand what is causing a performance cliff in a run length decoding step.
It eventually needs to fill a slice of an array with a constant value:

```
function fill(buf, from, to, val) {
    for (var i = from; i < to; ++i)
        buf[i] = val;
}
```

The function is only called with a single type of array and the other parameters are always within bounds. This code alone performs similar to the C code equivalent, with several 100 million array accesses per second and all is well. As expected, turbofan injects bounds checks to ensure the index stays in the valid range.

But when I add these bound checks explicitly to the function:

```
function fill(buf, from, to, val) {
    if (from < 0 || to < from || buf.length < to)
        throw new Error();
    for (var i = from; i < to; ++i)
        buf[i] = val;
}
```

the array writes are suddenly done with generic KEYED_STORE_IC, slowing down execution by a factor of *50*.

This is my test setup (1 million calls, ~4 billion writes):

```
var b = new Int32Array(10000);
for (var j = 0; j < 999999; ++j) {
    fill(b, j & 0xFFF, 6000 + (j % 0xFF), j);
}
```

The library should perform reasonably well across browsers and node 8.x/10.x. The test was done with v8.10 (V8 version 6.2.414.50).

Answer (score 2):

V8 developer here. How did you measure that difference? I can't reproduce it.

I've copy-pasted your code into `squarefree.com/shell/shell.html`, modulo renaming one of the functions:

```
function fill(buf, from, to, val) {
    for (var i = from; i < to; ++i)
        buf[i] = val;
}
function fill2(buf, from, to, val) {
    if (from < 0 || to < from || buf.length < to)
        throw new Error();
    for (var i = from; i < to; ++i)
        buf[i] = val;
}
var b = new Int32Array(10000);
var t1 = Date.now();
for (var j = 0; j < 999999; ++j) {
    fill(b, j & 0xFFF, 6000 + (j % 0xFF), j);
}
var t2 = Date.now();
for (var j = 0; j < 999999; ++j) {
    fill2(b, j & 0xFFF, 6000 + (j % 0xFF), j);
}
var t3 = Date.now();
```

After executing that (current Chrome Canary), I get:

```
> t2 - t1
< 5820
> t3 - t2
< 5887
```

So the manual bounds checks add a very minuscule performance penalty, which seems plausible.

My guess would be that you temporarily had a bug in the index computations and ended up having out-of-bounds accesses. That would explain why the generic IC was used, and why you were observing a major slowdown.

Comment: I initially just measured with `time` in bash. The difference only seems to come up in node 8 (3606ms vs 257419ms using your method); with node 10 (V8 6.8.275.32) I get the similar results as you (2415ms vs 2432ms). Whatever is causing this must've been fixed somewhere inbetween.